# how to add a MySQL Command to every page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a code I would like to run on every page, however it doesn't seem to work at all.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "User";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE users SET login_time=NOW() WHERE id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I have also tried the line

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET login-time='NOW()' WHERE id='$id'";
```

It comes back saying `Record updated successfully` But doesn't acctually update.

Thank you

Comment: what's in `db.php` ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($id);` output?

Comment: this is where i store the data for the user info, such as the id variable. That command should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: `login-time='now()'` is outright wrong. `login MINUS time = string` will not work. That should never have worked.

Comment: Marc B, it is acctually login_time=now() however i did try login_time='now()'

Comment: To notify people of your response, remember to type an @ symbol and then their name. Use tab to auto complete. For example: @MarcB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never work:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

query() calls either return a statement handle/object (success), or a boolean FALSE (failure). They will never return a boolean TRUE, meaning that this comparison can never ever succeed. You should never have gotten a "success" message, only the "failed" one.

Comment: Yes.. he should instead use `$conn->affected_rows`

Comment: i added this line to it, and it worked...  $id = $_SESSION['user_id']; but yet this was defined in the db.php file